# Why I don't receive email from customer form? (Magento 2.4)

Tags: email, magento2.4, email-templates

I've created a CMS page with a form where customers can submit some info & by clicking 'submit' Magento sends an email (with all the info provided into the form) to an address that I set by a custom configuration tab (**Stores** > **Configuration** > ***Vendor*** > ***Module***).

[image]

I developed it via TransportBuilder: I set up all those files such as email_templates.xml, I created the email template and I've already extended the Magento TransportBuilder class in order to attach a ZIP file to the email (I created the addAttachment() method).

Here's the function in my controller (the $templateVars param is an array that I pass correctly, already checked):

[image]

**But what is the problem?**

When I test this from localhost (working on a local MAMP server), I submit the form and suddenly I correctly receive the email with the right attachments etc. Perfect.

But when I test this on a live server the mail isn't delivered! Even logging with the module's own logger and checking the *Magento Sent Emails' Log*, they both say that the email was successfully sent but it doesn't arrive into my inbox! I tried to find a solution for days and days but I didn't manage to. Someone's got a solution?

Comment: Does your production server allow you to send emails using any from/sender address?

Comment: I actually don't know.. how can I check it?